# AJAX Request Not Sending Arabic characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I wrote jQuery post to send request to the server to get customers that their names begins with that request but the problem is it sends only english characters 
Here is the post code

```
console.log("1 - "+inputString); //return Arabic right
console.log("2 - "+decodeURIComponent(inputString)); //return arabic right
console.log("3 - "+encodeURIComponent(inputString)); //encoded Arabic 
inputString = decodeURIComponent(inputString); 
console.log(inputString); //also arabic right
$.post("<?= base_url(); ?>admin/customers/get_customer/"+inputString, function(data){
                alert(data); 
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
```

At the server side

```
function get_customer($customer)
    {
        header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        die($customer." - - ".utf8_decode($customer)." - - ".utf8_encode($customer)); //just for testing and all returns encoded characters 

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_name LIKE '$customer%' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
        $str = ""; 
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query) ):
            $str .= '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->customer_id.'\',\''.$result->customer_name.'\');">'.$result->customer_name.' </li>';
        endwhile;
        echo $str; 

    }
```

The character set in the view file is utf-8 by HTML & PHP
Also The charset of the jquery is UTF-8 
So what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it this is my solution

```
function get_customer($customer)
    {
        header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        $customer = urldecode($customer);//this is the solution decode the url 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_name LIKE '$customer%' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
        $str = ""; 
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query) ):
            $str .= '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->customer_id.'\',\''.$result->customer_name.'\');">'.$result->customer_name.' </li>';
        endwhile;
        echo $str; 

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this that I don't think the example in the question nor your solution show fully. URLs can only contain ASCII characters, so the only option is to encode the Arabic portion before sending the request. You'll need something like this when building your URL:

```
$.post("<?= base_url(); ?>.../"+encodeURIComponent(inputString), function(data){
  // ...
});
```

The second part, which your solution shows, is to decode the data on the server side:

```
function get_customer($customer) {
  $customer = urldecode($customer);
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and the problem was that the hoster had not communicated me the MySQL server upgrade. So basically I was connecting to the db using these queries

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$dbhandle);

mysql_query("SET CHARSET 'utf8'",$dbhandle);
```

then using this function instead of the previous

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $dbhandle);
```

I solved the problem.