# Solving this issue of sending arabic characters using ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, encoding

I'm using an AJAX form in order to send data to another page named 'show.php'.
Here is the source of pages:

**form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="ajaxsbmt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<div id="MyResult"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="response_norma.php" name="MyForm" onsubmit="xmlhttpPost('show.php', 'MyForm', 'MyResult', '<img src=\'indicator.gif\'>'); return false;">
      <input type="text" name="mytext" size="20">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="ok">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**show.php**

```
<?php
  echo $_REQUEST['mytext'];
?>
```

**ajaxsbmt.js**

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL, formname, responsediv, responsemsg) {
  var xmlHttpReq = false;
  var self = this;
  // xhr for Mozilla/Safari/Ie7
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  // xhr for all other versions of IE
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
  self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
      // When ready, put the response into the form
      updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText, responsediv);
    } else {
      // While waiting for the respnse, display a message
      updatepage(responsemsg, responsediv);
    }
  }
  self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring(formname));
}


function getquerystring(formname) {
  var form = document.forms[formname];
  var qstr = "";

  function GetElemValue(name, value) {
    qstr += (qstr.length > 0 ? "&" : "")
            + escape(name).replace(/\+/g, "%2B")
            + "="
            + escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
            ´//+ escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\n/g, "%0D");
  }

  var elemArray = form.elements;
  for (var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++) {
    var element = elemArray[i];
    var elemType = element.type.toUpperCase();
    var elemName = element.name;
    if (elemName) {
      if (
           elemType == "TEXT" 
        || elemType == "TEXTAREA" 
        || elemType == "PASSWORD" 
        || elemType == "BUTTON" 
        || elemType == "RESET" 
        || elemType == "SUBMIT" 
        || elemType == "FILE" 
        || elemType == "IMAGE" 
        || elemType == "HIDDEN"
      ) 
        GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);
      else if (elemType == "CHECKBOX" && element.checked) 
        GetElemValue(elemName, element.value ? element.value : "On");
      else if (elemType == "RADIO" && element.checked) 
        GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);
      else if (elemType.indexOf("SELECT") != -1)
        for (var j = 0; j < element.options.length; j++) {
          var option = element.options[j];
          if (option.selected) 
            GetElemValue(elemName, option.value ? option.value : option.text);
        }
    }
  }
  return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str, responsediv) {
  document.getElementById(responsediv).innerHTML = str;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When I type English characters in the filed, data transfer successfully and I receive them top of the form.

But when I try to type Arabic characters, I receive another data, something like encoded words. e.g: %u0633%u0644%u0627%u0645. %u0686%u0637%u0648%u0631%u06CC instead of:
 سلام. چطوری
(if you have font.)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you this error only with Arabic chars or every other language?

Comment: I tried Chinese chars. Chinese chars also have this problem.

Comment: Did you already try the solution mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8274269/1446848

Answer (score 6):

You're using `escape()` and some fancy custom replacements. Don't do this.

`escape()` is broken and there is very little reason to use it.

The function you're looking for is called `encodeURIComponent()`.

```
// use an array to hold the query string parts
var qstr = [];

qstr.appendParam = function(name, value) {
  this.push( 
     encodeURIComponent(name) 
     + (value > "" ? "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) : "")
  );
  return this;
}
qstr.toString = function () {
  return "?" + this.join("&");
}

// use like this:
qstr.appendParam("foo", "bar");
qstr.appendParam("arabic", "سلام. چطوری");

// now make a real query string.
qstr.toString() // "?foo=bar&arabic=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85.%20%DA%86%D8%B7%D9%88%D8%B1%DB%8C"
```

The above should replace your `GetElemValue()` function. Note how you can tweak objects by adding functions you need (like `appendParam()`) or overriding functions that are already there (like `toString()`).

Also note that you can return the array itself from your function `getquerystring()`. JavaScript calls `toString()` automatically in situations like this:

```
var url = "http://bla/" + qstr
```

Since `toString()` is overridden, the right thing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is your page is encoding the characters as unicode. For example, %u0633 is the first character in your string. That is normal, though I am surprised it is happening automatically.

Now, you need to decode them when displaying to the viewer.

It looks like this may be what you want:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

```
string utf8_decode ( string $data )
```

That function takes encoded input, which looks like "%u0079" or "%u0078" and turns it back into letters. When you try to display the string using PHP, wrap it in:

```
utf8decode("mystring")
```

I think show.php should look like:

```
<?php
  echo utf8decode($_REQUEST['mytext']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $orignialmytext = $_REQUEST['mytext'];
  $decodedmytext = urldecode($orignialmytext);
  echo $decodedmytext;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help:

`self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');`

The above code should set the character set of the AJAX Request to UTF-8.