# Problem with sending Arabic language using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer, arabic

I'm using this example https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp to get the suggested words, it works fine with english words, but when i type in Arabic language i note that the $q = $_REQUEST["q"] is giving unknown characters when i var_dump($q), this problem is happening when i use Internet Explorer on windows 10 but with Google Chrome, everything is good.

I guess the problem is related to utf8 in Ajax code that internet explorer couldn't recognize Arabic characters, but i don't know how to modify it.

```
function showHint(str) {
if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = 
   this.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

Any help please!

Comment: You have to pass a request header `Accept-Language`and pass the locale you want to support. If you will pass * it will support all languages. The example you are referring to, if you see in chrome developer tools in network tab, in request header the Accept language is `en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7,la;q=0.6,de;q=0.5` So modify this and you are good to go. How to set header in XMLHTTPRequest -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ajax issues, i don't know how to do it

Comment: add a line `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'ar')` after the line `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: bro the code works fine on google chrome without add this code xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'ar') but only on internet explorer i got the problem. When i added xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'ar') both of my browsers got the problem

Comment: You should Mention this in the question. How I am supoose to know that you’re facing this issue only in IE

Comment: sorry bro just now i knew it, actually i'm working on internet explorer not google chrome

Comment: Please remember to read through ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask), which covers things like this. You're asking people who know nothing about your problem, to help fix your problem, so make sure all the details are in your question so people don't waste time trying to solve problems you're _not_ having.

Comment: @sandanet see this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11096159/1675954